# How do I prevent ReSharper wrapping lamba expressions in method calls

Tags: c#, lambda, resharper

ReSharper turns this:

```
_cache.AddOrUpdate(key, k => new CacheEntry<TValue>(item), (k, old) => { old.Access(); return old; });
```

Into this:

```
_cache.AddOrUpdate(key, k => new CacheEntry<TValue>(item), (k, old) =>
                                                            {
                                                                old.Access();
                                                                return old;
                                                            });
```

How can I prevent the wrapping of the lambda in the last parameter?

Comment: It just appears as code formatting, there is no code change, just some indentation for readability.

Comment: Right.  I understand there is no material change.  What I'm trying to avoid is the wrapping, as indicated by the question title.  I don't want to wrap that lambda.

Comment: I'm voting to close the (my own) question.  The problem is that the code is in a multi-line lambda, and ReSharper is set to put statements on separate lines.  Since that is the desired behavior for code-cleanup, I'm just going to refactor such parameters into variable before calling the function.  Not my code, but I have to live with it, so I may as well clean it up a bit.

Answer (score -1):

This is just line breaks.

In Visual Studio, go to `RESHARPER` => `Options` => `Code Editing` => `C#` => `Line breaks and wrapping` and put your own preferences there.

Comment: I spent time looking at those settings before a posted the question.  Any idea which specific setting this is?

Comment: Probably anything under "Line Wrapping". "Wrap long lines" seems to be the top on/off switch.